# Почему метод onCreateOptionsMenu является boolean?

Tags: android, menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Это метод по умолчанию и он является boolean почему ?
Зачем возвращать true ? Знаю, что если будет false, то меню не создастся, вот не пойму почему именно boolean. Медот inflate итак же создает меню из xml разметки !

Comment: я конечно не совсем помню, но вроде параметр отвечает за показ меню

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отрывок с официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)):

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false
>   it will not be shown.

Возвращайте `true` если хотите отобразить меню и `false` если нет. Никакого прямого отношеня к `inflate`-у меню данный флаг не имеет. Скорее всего возвращаемое значение просто служит для удобства скрытия/показа меню и не более.